# Serialization of STL unordered_map

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, unordered-map

I have a program which uses an unordered map with this definition:

```
unordered_map<const char*, vector<pair<int, int> >, function<unsigned int (const char *str)> > myMap(30000, hashing);
```

where hashing is a function used for, well, hashing keys. My problem is -> how to serialize this kind of structure and deserialize it afterwards? I really need that, and to be fast and efficient as possible. I have been reading about boost libraries, but I don't understand much how to use them with this kind of stuff. I know there is some boost library for unordered maps, but, obviously I'm doing something wrong with it and the compiler throws a lot of errors. Can someone give me an example code that works on how to serialize this? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR** You cannot serialize `std::function`, use a regular predicate class instead.

---

Serializing a map (whatever its kind) is easy. At heart it is:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> Map;

void serialize(Serializer& out, Map const& map) {
    out << map.size();
    for (auto const& p: map) { out << p.first << p.second; }
}

Map deserialize(Deserializer& in) {
    Map map;

    size_t size = 0;
    in >> size;

    for (size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
        Map::key_type key;
        Map::mapped_type value;
        in >> key >> value;
        map[key] = value;
    }

    return map;
}
```

Except that in the general case both the comparator and allocator could be stateful right ?

```
void serialize(Serializer& out, Map const& map) {
+   out << map.value_compare() << map.get_allocator();

    out << map.size();
    for (auto const& p: map) { out << p.first << p.second; }
}

Map deserialize(Deserializer& in) {
+   Map::key_compare comparator;
+   Map::allocator_type allocator;
+
+   in >> comparator >> allocator;
+
+   Map map(comparator, allocator)

    size_t size = 0;
    in >> size;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
        Map::key_type key;
        Map::mapped_type value;
        in >> key >> value;
        map[key] = value;
    }

    return map;
}
```

So, in your case, assuming that Boost.Serialization knows how to handle `std::allocator` (it's stateless), how is it supposed to serialize `std::function<unsigned int(char const*)>` ?

Answer: it's impossible because `std::function` performs **type erasure** and this clashes with C++ statically typed nature (and its lack of introspection). Once a type has been erased, it is not possible, in general, to recover it.

You need the type of the comparator to be *explicit* in the type of the `map` OR to have an external mean to look it up. In any case, it may be hard to fit it into Boost.Serialization (context-less). You will probably be better up using a regular predicate class.

Comment: `in >> key >> value` isn't going to work with arbitrary strings

Comment: @JonathanWakely: It certainly work out of the box using `Boost.Serialization`. Whether using length-prefixing or escaping is up to the implementer.

Comment: Doh, sorry, I missed that you're writing to a `Serializer` not an `ostream`! It does indeed work then.

Comment: One little note on the type-erasure: It doesn't make this impossible per-se, just std::function<> does because it erases all but the "callability" of the object. If you had a type-erasure type that preserved callability and serializabilty, it would work!

Comment: @ltjax: you're right of course, this is what I tried to convey with the *it is not possible, **in general**, to recover it*; obviously if the type is crafted specifically as to allow it (which is generally a ad-hoc introspection mechanism), then it's possible.

Comment: Yea, it sounded a bit like it would be generally impossible to do serialize it once the type has been "erased". Just thought I would clarify that!